# mysql - design a table with a column that can have multiple values

Tags: php

I have a table with news.

```
id | title   | text    | date    | image
----------------------------------------------------------
1     HI      R u ok?   5/5/2013   image1.jpg
2   Good bye  Bye Bye   6/6/2013   image2.jpg, image3.jpg
```

And every piece of new can have more than image, any number of images.
I've tried to store in one column several images (like the example), but I don't know how exactly then display it like any news website.

```
Title
Text
Images
Date
```

How can I do this with a `foreach` or `while`?

Comment: You need to either duplicate all the data in a second row (with the second image, or normalize it into a second table with a foreign key back into this table.

Comment: and isn't there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using an `Images` table to store each image URL and the news ID it belongs to.

Comment: If the images are just attributes to the news entity then normalizing it out to another table gains little benefit but introduces considerable complexity. If in the scope of the application images where there own entity and had attributes associated with them then normalizing them would make sense

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use a second table where you use a foreign key to the id of your current table and an image path to the image.

Comment: if I do:

select news.title, news.text, news.date, images.image from news, images where news.id = images.id_new

i get repeated news

Comment: Yeah, check this tutorial on how to join the two tables.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp. A tip with inner join is to put it within a parenthesis. That makes the sql command much more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to add all of the images at the same place (and not, say, inlined in the text), you can just fetch all the records you want, and then split the multiple values with PHP's explode() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$My_SQL=mysql_query("select * from tbl_name where id=2");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($My_SQL)){
$title=$array["title"];
$text=$array["text"];
$date=$array["date"];
$images=$array["images"];
}
$image_arr=explode(',',$images);

Now all you images are available in array elements
```